# how to install aws-sdk for ruby on windows

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm using a Windows machine,and very new in ruby 
And in need to run AWS API for Ruby on windows

I've installed Ruby 2.1.4 
now I want to add  to aws-sdk to it :
after downloading and extracting the SDK files , I cant understand how can I install it

I've tried `gem install aws-sdk` , but I get an error of not finding 'aws' 
what do I nned to do ?

Comment: you're running it from the command line and not the Ruby console, right?  Note that `gem install` doesn't require downloading first; using gem should initiate a download & install.

Could also try using `gem install aws-sdk-v1`

Comment: firing the command from CMD givev this error : 
C:\Users\xxxxx>gem install aws-sdk-v1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    U+200F to IBM862 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM862

Comment: oh, ok....run `chcp` from the command line and see what codepage you have active.  My system is 437 and the install worked, might also try setting it to 1252 and trying again (command is `chcp 1252`, just make a note of your current setting so you can change it back if needed)

Comment: Not working on ether of thus numbers ...

Comment: Hmm...How did you do the install?  For windows, I use RubyInstaller (32-bit) from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ with devkit mingw64-32-4.7.2.

Comment: it turns out that because my windows in native to English , it is not working ... on my friend's pc it's working fine , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The following process worked for me:

1. Install Ruby.

   - I used rubyinstaller-2.2.5 downloaded from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)
2. open a Command Prompt

   - I used "Start Command Prompt with Ruby"
3. `gem install aws-sdk`

Example

```
C:\> gem install aws-sdk
Fetching: aws-sdk-2.6.18.gem (100%)
Successfully installed aws-sdk-2.6.18
Parsing documentation for aws-sdk-2.6.18
Installing ri documentation for aws-sdk-2.6.18
Done installing documentation for aws-sdk after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

C:\>
```

---